# kafkacat not available on windows to be able tp consume?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am learning the **Streaming with Spring Cloud Stream and Apache Kafka** from link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Mgni6AYnWg&t=790s.

I did found any utility for `kafkacat` for the windows environment. How can we do that?

Comment: i hope your have downloaded apache-kafka src folder to your system.  
kafkcat is just a simple tool to produce , consume & list topics. this same thing can be achieved using kafka-console-producer.bat, kafka-console-consumer.bat, and kafka-topics.bat

Answer (score 0):

Kafkacat doesn't come with Kafka tools

It's a separate utility on Github - https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat

And you need to build it for windows - [How can I install and configure KafkaCat in windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418295/how-can-i-install-and-configure-kafkacat-in-windows-machine)